# Drawing trendline over scatterplot using smoothScatter in R

Tags: r

I want to do a multiple linear regression in R where the two independent variables and the dependent variable are questions that are answered on a Likert scale (1 = 'not at all worried' to 5 = 'extremely worried).  I want to check the assumptions before I run the analyses.

However, I can't find a way to check the assumption of linearity. Normally, I would draw a scatterplot to see whether there is a linear tendency in the data, indicating that a linear regression is the right analysis to use. However, drawing a regular scatterplot results in a graph with 25 dots, because there's 1 to 5 and the x axis and on the y axis, and this is just not very informative.

Using smoothScatter I made a plot that is a bit more useful, but it's not really enough to determine whether the relationship is linear or not. I would like to draw a trend line/line of best fit through the smooth scatterplot. How can I do this?

EDIT:
The code beneath provides data and scatter plots similar to what I've described:

```
data <- matrix(nrow = 200, ncol = 3)

data[,1] <- sample(1:5, 200, replace = TRUE) #independent
data[,2] <- sample(1:5, 200, replace = TRUE) #independent
data[,3] <- sample(1:5, 200, replace = TRUE) #dependent

plot(data[,1], data[,3])  #regular scatterplot -> 25 dots
plot(data[,2], data[,3])  #regular scatterplot -> 25 dots

smoothScatter(data[,1], data[,3]) 
smoothScatter(data[,2], data[,3])
```

Comment: It will help if you provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited the question!

Comment: As your sample data is random it will be quite challenging to visualize a convincing example. You can look into `scatterplot3d` which is a userfriendly package to plot multivariate data in a 3d graph.